# Can't persist user logins when using Devise and Omniauth in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise, omniauth

This is a frequently asked question, and I have dug around previous answers to see if I can get to the bottom of this to no avail.

User logins are bound to the browser session and I would like them to be bound to a 30 day cookie.

Because not all users will have passwords as they can authenticate using twitter or facebook I have created a `remember_token` on the Users table (**I haven't done anything to reference it in the User model, do I need to?**).

In my `omniauth_callbacks_controller` I have the included the Devise Rememberable module;

```
include Devise::Controllers::Rememberable
```

And when it comes to saving the user session I have;

```
if user.persisted? || user.save
  user.remember_me = true
  sign_in_and_redirect user, event: :authentication
```

After reading an article about the issues with not having a password I also have the following in my User model;

```
before_create :rememberable_value
```

And;

```
def rememberable_value
  self.remember_token ||= Devise.friendly_token
end
```

In any of my tests the session is not saved between browser closes/opens and nothing is ever set in the database for the User's `remember_token`

In my Devise initializer I have;

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.remember_for = 30.days
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
  config.extend_remember_period = true
  secure_option = (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?) ? false : true
  config.rememberable_options = { secure: secure_option }
  config.password_length = 8..128
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_OAUTH_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_OAUTH_SECRET']
  config.omniauth :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_OAUTH_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_OAUTH_SECRET']
end
```

A nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated!